# Error when updating API Management with Azure CLI - hostnameConfigurations

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to update my APIM with a new hostname using the Azure CLI.

When doing this

```
$hostConfiguration = '[{
    "hostName": "myhostname.com",
    "type": "Proxy",
    "keyVaultId": "https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret"
}]'


az apim update --name "apim-name" --resource-group "rg-name" --set hostnameConfigurations=$hostConfiguration
```

I get this :

```
Unable to build a model: Cannot deserialize as [HostnameConfiguration] an object of type <class 'str'>, DeserializationError: Cannot deserialize as [HostnameConfiguration] an object of type <class'str'>
```

What is wrong with the way I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to convert the json to string before storing in a variable.

I made use of https://tools.knowledgewalls.com/jsontostring to convert your json to string

[image]

**Updated Snippet**

```
$hostConfiguration ='[{\"hostName\":\"myhostname.com\",\"type\":\"Proxy\",\"keyVaultId\":\"https:\/\/mykeyvault.vault.azure.net\/secrets\/mysecret\"}]'

az apim update --name "apim-name" --resource-group "rg-name" --set hostnameConfigurations=$hostConfiguration
```